# Convert function into async function

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, subprocess, python-asyncio

I need to rewrite my python function so that it can be `async` executable.

This function is given as example:

```
import asyncio
from sse_starlette.sse import EventSourceResponse

async def run_command():
    command = "echo test1 && sleep 2 && echo test2 && sleep 2 && echo test3 && echo done"

    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
        command, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
    )

    while True:
        output = await proc.stdout.readline()
        if not output:
            return
        yield output.decode().strip()

async def predict():
        return EventSourceResponse(run_command())
```

Now I'm trying to convert the following function into async function as in above:

```
import subprocess
def run_command():
      command = "echo test1 && sleep 2 && echo test2 && sleep 2 && echo test3 && echo done"
      with subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=-1) as p: 
        char = p.stdout.read(1)
        while char != b'':  
            print(char.decode('UTF-8','ignore'), end='', flush=True)
            char = p.stdout.read(1)
```

This function is similar to the one in the example, but it prints out each character instead of each line and uses `subprocess` instead of `asyncio`. How can I convert my subprocess based function to an async function?

I tried this but I'm getting an error:

```
async def run_command():

    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
        command, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
    )

    while True:
        output = await proc.stdout.read(1)
        if not output:
            return
        while output != b'':  
            print(output.decode('UTF-8','ignore'), end='', flush=True)
            yield output.decode('UTF-8','ignore')
            output = p.stdout.read(1)
```

Comment: Have you tried the "obvious", just changing `subprocess.Popen(...)` to `await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(...)`, and `p.stdout.read(1)` to `await await p.stdout.read(1)`, etc.?

Comment: @user4815162342 I rewrote the function but I'm getting an error. Please take a look, I've updated the question

Comment: Unfortunately you didn't write what error you are getting. Also, your function uses "yield" for some reason, whereas the original function you're converting didn't. Finally, you haven't shown how you're consuming (calling) the function.

Comment: @user4815162342 Right now the process simply prints out first character of the first word and exists without outputing the rest. I'd like to fix that. My function is intended to be async (like in the provided example) and that's why I added 'yield'. I'm calling the function the same way as in the example (async def predict())

Comment: Please edit the question to include the additional information. Also, please show how you are calling the function. Finally, note that `yield` is not mandatory for an async function. Maybe you don't need it.